# Un-typed conditional object member does not trigger type error

Tags: typescript

In the following code:

```
type Schema = {
    a: string;
    b?: string;
}

// This does not error, even though it will have an non-typed property
const schema1: Schema = {
    a: 'foo',
    ...(true ? {c: 'bar'} : undefined)
}

// This errors, as expected
const schema2: Schema = {
    a: 'foo',
    c: 'bar'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLxQN4CgoFSoBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYDc+hARgPykU0PMC+uXAHohUACoJqZKABMA9hGm05wKBEqU5lADRqAbhFpRgCOQFd6CKNVUB3agBsHUBKgNEjy2gFpQkGVBgmpCUoLhwcrQU5IgoqACMpPBIaJg4LAQkUADkAGZyctnaGVAAdOUAFFRm0Ow4cKTZrKiU2XxQpGa0MhC5dBAyAJS4AsKiElJqGlpkuqjSEAAekHDAA+GR0WSxaABMSTvoWHiERI35hcWnDTnNrSNAA)

Even though `Schema` does not define a `c` member, the first case will not throw a type error.

Can someone explain

- Is this expected behaviour? If yes, why is that so?
- How can this be written in a way that works as intended (be able to throw when a conditional object member that is un-typed is added to the object)?

Comment: Fundamentally, given structural typing (see e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), both `schema1` and `schema2` _are_ valid `Schema`s. [Excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks) are only applied in the simplest cases, when the compiler can trivially see you're creating completely inaccessible properties, not when conditionally merging objects.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77652837/un-typed-conditional-object-member-does-not-trigger-type-error#comment136898818_77652837) They're valid `Schema`s because they're *subtypes* of `Schema` (they're both `Schema` plus `c`). [Excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks) are, as Jon said, only for the simplest of cases. (I'm sure there's a previous version of this question we should point it to...)

Comment: Aah, ok, this clears things up, thank you both. Feel free to add it as an answer so that I can properly accept it. Cheers